# Xcode C++ Console: Is there a limit on number of input characters?

Tags: c++, xcode, string, console, limit

When I paste or type a string that contains ~1000 characters into the console, ¿'s (upside down question marks) start appearing in the input. Once they start appearing, I can't delete the characters I've entered, and pressing enter yields even more ¿'s. The program only continues after hitting delete once and pressing enter again.

[image: Note the ¿'s after the input and those that appeared from pressing enter]

When I *cout* << the string obtained from the input , an amount of characters about equal to the number of ¿'s that appeared in the input are missing from the string. There were no missing characters in the input, just the strange extra ¿'s.

It's not an issue with unknown characters, as it happens even with simple letters and digits. This doesn't happen when the input is entered in pieces. Is there some sort of limit on how many characters can be entered into the console at once, or is this a different error? And can it be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Dylan, I got myself here trying to answer a question at Stack Overflow - Portuguese version. The code in question compiled using my system (Arch Linux, console, GCC) but not in a Mac Sierra (Xcode, LLVM) owned by the guy that asked. After my comments, he tested in a Linux VM (Ubuntu) and it worked like mine had. It had an input ranging from 1 to 300,000. Somewhere along the way, it breaks and needs to be forcefully terminated. I think this should be answered properly by those who knows a little more than us. Really intriguing - might as well be interesting!